# Given two arrays find the index k that minimizes the sum A[i]*|B[i]-B[k]|

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I am given two arrays that contains natural numbers , A and B , and I need to find the index k that minimizes the sum A[i] * |B[i]-B[k]| from i=0 to n-1.
(Both arrays have the same length)
Its obviously easy to do in O(n^2) , I just calculate all sums for all k between 0 and n-1, but I need a better run time complexity.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @Dukeline:  I assume he just meant absolute value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this in time O(nlogn) by first sorting both arrays based on the values in B, and then performing a single scan.

Once the arrays are sorted, then B[i]>=B[k] if i>k and B[i]<=B[k] if i<= k, so the sum can be rewritten as:

```
sum A[i] * abs(B[i]-B[k]) = sum A[i]*(B[i]-B[k])  for i=k..n-1
                            + sum A[i]*(B[k]-B[i])  for i=0..k-1

    = sum A[i]*B[i] for i=k..n-1
      - B[k] * sum A[i] for i=k..n-1
      + B[k] * sum A[i] for i = 0..k-1
      - sum A[i]*B[i] for i = 0..k-1
```

You can precalculate all of the sums in time O(n) which then lets you evaluate the target sum at every position in O(n) and select the value for k which gives the best score.

Answer (score 5):

I believe I can do this is O(n log n).

First, sort the `B` array, applying the same permutation to the `A` array (and remembering the permutation).  This is the O(n log n) part. Since we sum over all i, applying the same permutation to the A and B arrays does not change the minimum.

With a sorted `B` array, the rest of the algorithm is actually O(n).

For each k, define an array C<sub>k</sub>[i] = |B[i] - B[k]|

(Note: We will not actually construct C<sub>k</sub>...  We will just use it as a concept for easier reasoning.)

Observe that the quantity we are trying to minimize (over k) is the sum of A[i] * C<sub>k</sub>[i].  Let's go ahead and give that a name:

Define: S<sub>k</sub> = Σ A[i] * C<sub>k</sub>[i]

Now, for any particular k, what does C<sub>k</sub> look like?

Well, C<sub>k</sub>[k] = 0, obviously.

More interestingly, since the B array is sorted, we can get rid of the absolute value signs:

- C<sub>k</sub>[i] = B[k] - B[i], for 0 <= i < k
- C<sub>k</sub>[i] = 0, for i = k
- C<sub>k</sub>[i] = B[i] - B[k], for k < i < n

Let's define two more things.

Definition: T<sub>k</sub> = Σ A[i] for 0 <= i < k

Definition: U<sub>k</sub> = Σ A[i] for k < i < n

(That is, T<sub>k</sub> is the sum of the first k-1 elements of A.  U<sub>k</sub> is the sum of all but the first k elements of A.)

The key observation: Given S<sub>k</sub>, T<sub>k</sub>, and U<sub>k</sub>, we can compute S<sub>k+1</sub>, T<sub>k+1</sub>, and U<sub>k+1</sub> in constant time.  How?

T and U are easy.

The question is, how do we get from S<sub>k</sub> to S<sub>k+1</sub>?

Consider what happens to C<sub>k</sub> when we go to C<sub>k+1</sub>.  We simply add B[k+1]-B[k] to every element of C from 0 to k, and we subtract the same amount from every element of C from k+1 to n (prove this).  That means we just need to add T<sub>k</sub> * (B[k+1] - B[k]) and subtract U<sub>k</sub> * (B[k+1] - B[k]) to get from S<sub>k</sub> to S<sub>k+1</sub>.

Algebraically...  The first k terms of S<sub>k</sub> are just the sum from 0 to k-1 of A[i] * (B[k] - B[i]).

The first k terms of S<sub>k+1</sub> are the sum from 0 to k-1 of A[i] * (B[k+1] - B[i])

The difference between these is the sum, from 0 to k-1, of (A[i] * (B[k+1] - B[i]) - (A[i] * (B[k] - B[i])).  Factor out the A[i] terms and cancel the B[i] terms to get the sum from 0 to k-1 of A[i] * (B[k+1] - B[k]), which is just T<sub>k</sub> * (B[k+1] - B[k]).

Similarly for the last n-k-1 terms of S<sub>k</sub>.

Since we can compute S<sub>0</sub>, T<sub>0</sub>, and U<sub>0</sub> in linear time, and we can go from S<sub>k</sub> to S<sub>k+1</sub> in constant time, we can calculate all of the S<sub>k</sub> in linear time.  So do that, remember the smallest, and you are done.

Use the inverse of the sort permutation to get the `k` for the original arrays.

Comment: +1 for a correct algorithm - my answer omits applying the inverse of the sort permutation

Answer (score 3):

Here is O(NlogN) solution. 
Example

```
A 6 2 5 10 3 8 7
B 1 5 4 3  6 9 7
```

1) First sort the two array to increasing of order of B. A's element is just binding with B. 
  After sort, we get

```
 A  6 10 5 2 3 7
 B  1 3  4 5 6 7
```

Since B are in order now. We have

```
n-1
sum A[i]|B[i]-B[k]| 
i=0

 k-1                 n-1
=sum A[i](B[k]-B[i])+ sum A[i](B[k]-B[i])
 i=0                 i=k+1
      k-1       n-1          k-1           n-1
=B[k](sum A[i] -sum A[i]) - (sum A[i]B[i]- sum A[i]B[i])
      i=0      i=k+1        i=0           i=k+1
```

2) We calculate prefix sum of array A sumA=0 6 16 21 23 26 33

```
          i=e
With sumA sum A[i] can be calcuated in O(1) time for any s and e. 
          i=s
```

For the same reason, we can calculate A[i]B[i]'s prefix sum. 
So for each k, to check its value, it just take O(1) time. 
So total time complexity is `O(NlogN)+O(N).`